# PostgreSQL dow conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, postgresql-9.1

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to look up the day of the week for a block of dates all at once? I can use

```
SELECT extract(dow from timestamp '2012-08-27')
```

to get one day at a time, but I want to feed it a month or so of data at once. I have created a "calendar" table in my database that has one column, date, as the primary key formatted yyyy-MM-dd.

If I wanted to run this extract against every day in September, is there a simple way to do it? Could I write a function and feed a start and end date into it?

Comment: +1 for explaining what you want to do and including your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best I can guess from your description, this:

```
 SELECT the_date_column_name, extract(dow from the_date_column_name)
 FROM calendar
 WHERE date_trunc('month', the_date_column_name) = DATE '2012-09';
```

... or the btree-indexable version:

```
 SELECT the_date_column_name, extract(dow from the_date_column_name)
 FROM calendar
 WHERE the_date_column_name BETWEEN DATE '2012-09-01' AND (DATE '2012-09-01' + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

should do the job.

You can use `>= DATE '2012-09-01'` and `< DATE '2012-10-01'` instead of `BETWEEN` if you prefer; it avoids the messy construction of the end date and works the same.

To wrap it in a function you need to work out how you want to call it and how you want the results returned first. Do you want to pass a start and end date range? A date that represents the 1st day of the month of interest? What? And how do you want the results returned?

BTW, if your column is actually named `"date"` as your description suggests, change its name. `DATE` is an SQL keyword and type name. You can use it as a user identifier in some circumstances but it's a bad idea; choose a better name.

Comment: Thank you! That works. Sorry, a little new to some of this stuff. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @pkracer No worries. See updated answer re the issue of wrapping it in a function ... though I'd have to ask why you needed to with a query like this, it doesn't seem very useful to encapsulate in a function.

Comment: Well I am trying to come up with a simple solution to a hotel rate look up where a different rate is charged on the weekends. I need some way of identifying what day of the week a certain date is. Right now I have a room_rate table that, for example, has room A with 5 rate_ids (rows) associated with it. Each of the id's has a start date, end date, weekday rate, and weekend rate associated with it. The start date and end dates span a couple months. When a user puts in dates to search, I need the database to assign the correct rate based on the day of the week.

Comment: @pkracer OK, so you really want to write an `is_weekend` function that returns `SELECT extract(dow from $1) IN (0,6)`, yes? Then use that in `CASE WHEN is_weekend(somedate) THEN weekend_rate ELSE weekday_rate END` ? Or just omit the function wrapper and write `CASE WHEN extract(dow from querydate) IN (0,6) THEN weekend_rate ELSE weekday_rate END`

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_weekend(timestamptz) RETURNS boolean AS $$ SELECT extract(dow from $1) IN (0,6) $$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE;` . For the meaning of `IMMUTABLE` see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html, but basically `IMMUTABLE` says the return value depends *only* on the argument so it can be used as an index expression in functional indexes. I used `timestamptz` because date up-casts to `timestamptz` but `timestamptz` doesn't downcast to date, so it's easier to call this way. I haven't marked it `STRICT` though it is so it can be inlined.

Comment: wow man. Thank you, thank you! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. You saved me so much time! You are awesome and so is this website.